# This is the watch that I (have/had/--) lost. -- what's the difference?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I've got a sentence on a learner's site, "This is the watch that I had lost" and now it's puzzling me. What's the rule to use the Past Perfect here? And why should I use specifically this tense?

It's stated, that this sentence is right and well-formed. But if someone replaced "had" by "have":
"This is the watch that I have lost", it would be impossible unless the watch is shown on a photo. Is it right?

Why can't I just use the Past Simple here: "This is the watch that I lost" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, what you would ordinarily say is

> This is the watch that I lost.

If you are *required* by the imbecility of testwriters to use a perfect, it must be a past perfect.

Because you now have the watch, you cannot say that you *have lost* it (except in a very unlikely 'experiential' sense of the perfect). Consequently, only the past perfect would be at all likely.

- CORRECTION, thanks to **Sydney**: It is also possible that you **don't** have the watch but are "showing a photo of" it; in this case the present perfect would be appropriate—but not **required**.

However, the past perfect is not *required*; in fact, it is inappropriate unless there is in the discourse some salient past time to which the perfect is related. For instance:

> Officer Thomas arrested me for behaving suspiciously, even though I told him I was looking for my watch. But my friend Joe went back and found  it, right where I was looking. This is the very watch that I had lost!

Comment: Maybe "This is the watch that I have lost" is possible if you are showing a photo of the watch!

Comment: @Sydney O cunning! I'm gonna steal that.

Comment: @Sydney, I've asked about that on the post. That's a really weird implication of using Present Perfect for me.

Comment: @tsul So you did. I should have read more attentively.

Comment: @tsul: I read this first thing in the morning, and missed the details.